# What sorting algorithm would this be named?

Tags: python, sorting

I have been asked to implement a Quick Sort algorithm however I may have failed to do so and implemented something else (that still sorts). However while searching for its name I have not been able to find its real name.

Complexity <s>seems to be O(n*ln(n))</s> is O(n) if the list is already sorted and O(n*n) at worst.

Here is the code :

```
def sort(L):
    S = [L[0]]
    for i in range(1,len(L)):
        addEnd = True
        for j in range(len(S)):
            if L[i] < S[j]:
                addEnd = False
                S.insert(j, L[i])
                break
        if addEnd:
            S.insert(len(S), L[i])
    return S
```

Thank you for helping me !

Comment: This looks like some sort of insertion sort.  btw a bubble sort is `O(n)` if the list is sorted.

Comment: Yeah it does however it never skips a number and uses an input array and outputs one.

Comment: I don't know where you got O(n log n) from. It's O(n) in the best case, when the input list is sorted.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I had another version in mind that was O(n*ln(n)) and the code was very similar, I'll correct it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your function fails if the length of the input is empty. But apart from that (whose fix is trivial), a quick [Hypothesis test](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) could not find a counterexample.

It is a **not**-[in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

A single-element list is already sorted, so your initial result is the first element of the input.
Then you iterate over each remaining element of the input, and search its position in the always-sorted result and **insert** it there.